# Replicate Oracle's RANGE BETWEEN windowing clause syntax with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012, window-functions

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT 
item_id, 
date,
(avg *  stddev(value) over(partition by item_id order by to_date(date,'yyyymm')
RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
+
price *  stddev(value2) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY to_date(date,'yyyymm')
RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
) as a
from table1
```

Is there any way possible to replicate the functionality of `RANGE BETWEEN` in SQL Server? Ranging between the current month and the 11 previous months.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the 2012 release, SQL Server added support for window functions just like what you are doing here in Oracle. The only difference will be the date handling, since Oracle has a unique syntax for date interval literal values (e.g. "INTERVAL '11' MONTH").

For info on window functions in SQL Server 2012, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

For info on date range handling, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx
Unfortunately, MS SQL Server does not fully implement RANGE like Oracle does... Seems that there is no simple workaround.

<unsigned value specification> PRECEDING
Specified with <unsigned value specification>to indicate the number of rows or values to precede the current row. This specification is not allowed for RANGE.

Comment: Right you are, apologies; I guess I need to read closer! Doing some more research, contrary to the hype, it looks like Microsoft is indeed still trailing the field, with no support for interval-based frames (what you're trying to do) and several other areas related to window functions also missing. 
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server-part-2-the-frame/